# how to dismiss DialogFragment from lambda specified in caller Kotlin

Tags: android, lambda, kotlin

I'm running the GirlQualitiesChoiceDialog from fragment like below:

```
        girlType.setOnClickListener {
              GirlQualitiesChoiceDialog.show(activity, InitialDataSet.instance.QUALITY_TYPE_COLOR){
              Picasso.with(context).load(it.resId).into(colorTypeImage as ImageView)
            //GirlQualitiesChoiceDialog.this.dismiss()   - need to dismiss the created dialog
              }
         }
```

Where specify the listener. What i need is to dismiss the dialog after i load the picture. **GirlQualitiesChoiceDialog.this.dismiss()**  is not working.

Can anybody advise me please how can I dismiss GirlQualitiesChoiceDialog in here ? Suppose I would need to pass the dialog callback somehow to lambda, but can't realize how.

Below is the code of my Dialog:

```
class GirlQualitiesChoiceDialog : DialogFragment() {

    companion object {
        val ARG_QUALITY_TYPE = "ARG_QUALITY_TYPE"

        private lateinit var itemClickInterface: (Quality) -> Unit

        fun show(activity: Activity, qualityType: Int, itemClick: (Quality) -> Unit) {
            itemClickInterface = itemClick
            GirlQualitiesChoiceDialog().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putInt(ARG_QUALITY_TYPE, qualityType)
                }
            }.show((activity as AppCompatActivity).supportFragmentManager, TAG)
        }
    }

    private lateinit var adapter: QualitiesAdapter

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {

        val choiceDialogView = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(horizontal_list_view, null)
        val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
        choiceDialogView.horisontalCardsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager)

        with(ItemClickSupport.addTo(choiceDialogView.horisontalCardsRecyclerView)) {
            setOnItemLongClickListener { recyclerView, position, v ->
                val quality = v.getTag() as Quality;
                dismiss()
                true
            }
        }

        var qualityType = arguments.getInt(ARG_QUALITY_TYPE)

        var title = -1
        when (qualityType) {
            InitialDataSet.instance.QUALITY_TYPE_COLOR -> {
                title = R.string.choose_color_type
                adapter = QualitiesAdapter(InitialDataSet.instance.qualities, itemClickInterface)
            }
        }

        choiceDialogView.horisontalCardsRecyclerView.adapter = adapter

        return AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setView(choiceDialogView)
                .create()
    }
}
```

and adapter

```
class QualitiesAdapter(val qualities: List<Quality>, val itemClick: (Quality) -> Unit) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<QualitiesAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.selection_card, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(view, itemClick)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bindForecast(qualities[position])
}

override fun getItemCount() = qualities.size

class ViewHolder(view: View, val itemClick: (Quality) -> Unit) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

    fun bindForecast(quality: Quality) {
        with(quality) {
            Picasso.with(itemView.context).load(resId).into(itemView.selectionImage)
            (itemView as BaseCardView).setStatusLabel(desc)
            itemView.setTag(quality)
            itemView.setOnClickListener { itemClick(this) }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html#qualified

Comment: It's not what I can use in here. I can do only this@AddGirlFragment but can't this@GirlQualitiesChoiceDialog. AddGirlFragment  is a fragment from which I open GirlQualitiesChoiceDialog. But I need to dismiss GirlQualitiesChoiceDialog. So I need to pass some link to GirlQualitiesChoiceDialog into a setOnClickListener  body.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you return the instance of the dialog from your show method then you can dismiss it in the call back.

Change show in GirlQualitiesChoiceDialog something like the following:

```
    fun show(activity: Activity, qualityType: Int, itemClick: (Quality) -> Unit): GirlQualitiesChoiceDialog {
        itemClickInterface = itemClick
        val dialog = GirlQualitiesChoiceDialog().apply {
            arguments = Bundle().apply {
                putInt(ARG_QUALITY_TYPE, qualityType)
            }
        }
        dialog.show((activity as AppCompatActivity).supportFragmentManager, TAG)
        return dialog
    }
```

Here's the listener code:

```
girlType.setOnClickListener {
    val dialog = GirlQualitiesChoiceDialog.show(activity, InitialDataSet.instance.QUALITY_TYPE_COLOR) {
        Picasso.with(context).load(it.resId).into(colorTypeImage as ImageView)
        dialog.dismiss()
    }
}
```